# MySql trigger with a return value

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a employee table like below

```
    emp_id    emp_name
        1     abc
        2     def
        3     ghi
```

**emp_id is int and auto_increment

can I get a trigger like, when I insert a new row with emp_name as "def", since I already have a record with emp_name as "def", I need to abort the new sql insert query and return the emp_id of the existing record. 2 in this case.

Comment: There is no return value since you don't call a trigger. It gets called automatically

Comment: *when I insert a new row* ... you execute `INSERT` query which cannot return values. If you need a value you must execute `SELECT`. *I need to abort the new sql insert query* Create unique index by `emp_name`. Trigger not needed. *return the emp_id of the* Knowing `emp_name` value use it in `WHERE` clause of `SELECT` and obtain `emp_id` value (either newly assigned or existed). For to distinguish does it is newly assigned or not analyse `affected rows` value returned as `INSERT` execution ststus.